# Firefox 29.0.1 WebSocket problems

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

Has anyone managed to use websockets with latest firefox (29.0.1). Connection is established but no messages are sent to the server or received from the server.

Also tried to run http://www.websocket.org/echo.html example against my server and websocket.org but nothing. Everything works perfectly in older firefox and chrome.

Does anyone know what could cause it?

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable the websocket:

open `about:config` in firefox toolbar as:

[image]

then setting the `network.websocket.enabled` preferences to `true`

[image]

Finally re-try to http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: WebSockets are disabled by default in Firefox ?!

Comment: @vtortola By default is enabled, but some plug-in (such as Tor-Button) can disable the web-socket.

Comment: don't have this config... firefox 39.0